# R: Save caret xgboost trained model as binary ( .model)

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, r-caret, training-data

I've created my xgboost model. It worked like this:

```
my_model <- caret::train( ... )
```

As a result i got this object:

```
> class(my_model)
[1] "train"         "train.formula"
```

In my Global Environment i see description of "my_model":
[print screen of environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYle6.png)

First of all - model works fine, everything OK with it. Also I can save this model as .RDA or .RDS object and loading it works just fine. But for my data engineer colleague I need to save it in some specific binary format - *.model.

So when I try to use **xgb.save** function directly to 'my_model', its obviously doesnt work cuz its class != 'xgb.Booster'. So I googled it, and read that I need to save 'my_model$finalModel'. It looks fine - its class is correct:

```
> class(my_model$finalModel)
[1] "xgb.Booster"
```

I can save model like this. But its filesize is really small, and when my colleague tries to load it to his Spark system, it looks like empty file. And it really too small:

```
> object_size(my_model$finalModel)
447 kB
```

So looks like 'my_model$finalModel' is only small part of 'my_model' which doesnt work for me.

The question is - How can I save it as *.model format? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `xgb.save(my_model$finalModel, "xgb.model")` will save model in binary format as `.model`.

Comment: As I wrote in my message, u can see that it doesn't work:
'I can save model like this. But its filesize is really small, and when my colleague tries to load it to his Spark system, it looks like empty file. And it really too small'

Also when I try to xgb.load my saved .model file - it burst my screen with errors